# "Official" formulae for association rules?

Tags: association-rules

Since I haven't found a good-enough package in Python for association rules learning, I am manually coding up my own.

However, I have seen conflicting information about exactly *what* the formulae for support, confidence, and lift (three association rules) are. For example, one resource tells me that, when looking at the support of two items *A* and *B* in the transaction basket *T*, you're supposed to examine all cases when *A* **and** *B* occur in *T* and divide that by the number of transactions. Another resource tells me it's *A* **or** *B*. Can anyone share the canonical formulae for these rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for online. I'm going to leave this here for anyone running into a similar problem in the future: https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch6.pdf. Look on page four of that document for support and confidence.

[image]